# How do I recieve dropbox authorization code?

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, dropbox-api

I'm stuck trying to get a client-side authorization token from Dropbox, I've followed the instructions [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauth-guide?_tk=guides_lp&_ad=deepdive2&_camp=oauth) and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#auth-token-from_oauth1), but still not getting authorized. As stated in the links provided above I'm suppose to make a request to an end-point as this: `https//www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=...&client_id=...&redirect_uri=...`, which I did, but still not getting redirected back with authorization code (based on the authorization flow chosen) that would then be exchange for a bearer access token using this [call](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-token). The bearer access token is then supposed to be used for all subsequent call.

What I'm I doing wrong here? Also is the way I can provide a permanent authentication without having to call the authorization URL for very request to the API? I've been stuck for this. help please.

#### Source code

```
 if (process.env) {
      const appKey = process.env.REACT_APP_KYUNISTUDIO_APP_KEY;
      const appSecretKey = process.env.REACT_APP_KYUNISTUDIO_SECRET_KEY;

      const authToken = () => {
        const headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'};

        fetch(`https//www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=<${appKey}>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000`, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers:headers,
        })
        .then(res => res.json)
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
      }
      authToken();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[The /oauth2/authorize endpoint](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-authorize) is a web page that you should direct the end-user to, not an API endpoint to access programmatically, as you're attempting to do here with your `fetch` call. For example, you can redirect the user there by setting `window.location` to the /oauth2/authorize URL.

Since you're using the 'token' flow, you'll get the access token back on the URL fragment on the redirect URI. You can read that back using `window.location.hash`.

Once you have the access token, you can use that for future calls without going through the authorization flow again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand I shouldn't call the redirection webpage as an endpoint API, but I'm still a bit knocked off. If it's won't be much of a bother, could you please write the code so I can comprehend. I haven't worked with the JavaScript `windows.location` BOM before so I don't quite get it.

Comment: @Romeo For the redirect, in browser JavaScript that would just be like `window.location =  "https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?...
". And here's an example of parsing the result from the official Dropbox API v2 JavaScript: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/b2353edeb221ec17b8e70a1d8fd4799e2f1f031d/examples/javascript/auth/index.html#L48

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate.